# Creating a timeline?

Tags: html, css, timeline

I'd like to create something similar to https://fleximize.com/careers-of-the-founders/ - I have an idea in mind about a personal project that could use such timelines. As I don't know much about programming (only the basis of html/css), my go-to solution would probably be dirty and heavy. I was wondering if you guys had any advices or methods to create such timelines in a customizable way? Should I use mysql to stock the datas first? I've looked at Google Charts but it's not really what I need, as I'd like to customize it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just right click and inspect element. You will find out how they have done it-dirty,heavy

Comment: If you want to go hard in the paint, use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) and load the data via json.  It might be out of your wheelhouse if you only know html/css, but you're probably going to need to use javascript in this project if you are trying to dynamically load data.  If you want something simple try [this css solution](https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/)